# How can I implement/use browser using lwuit in j2me?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am new to LWUIT, its indeed a great fun to use it so far. Currently I have to use its browser component to send and receive data to and from the server. Can anybody give me an insight about it or a tutorial so that I can get working into it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are using Browser for sending & Receiving Data, you can use HttpConnection for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you intend to have browser specific functionality like XML, HTML page rendering in your application than read the following articles

- [HTML Component Writeup In Ofir's Blog](http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2010/02/html-component-writeup-in-ofir-blog.html)
- [Mobile web and HTML inside JavaME with LWUIT](http://www.nextgenmoco.com/2010/02/mobile-web-and-html-inside-javame-with.html) {Suggested by @Baqueta, Thanks}
- [Download LWUIT 1.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html) and check project '**Browser**' under folder '*apps*' in lwuit root directory.

.

If you intend to implement communication between client and server using LWUIT than refer **`LWUIT4IO`** library packaged with [LWUIT 1.5 download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html). Read the following articles to better understand 'LWUIT4IO' the library.

- [Introducing LWUIT For IO (LWUIT4IO)](http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2010/08/introducing-lwuit-for-io-lwuit4io.html)
- [Parsing In LWUIT & LWUIT4IO](http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2011/08/parsing-in-lwuit-lwuit4io.html)
- [Logging & Caching In LWUIT4IO](http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2011/05/logging-caching-in-lwuit4io.html)

.

If you intend to communicate with the server from mobile client purely for data exchange then have a look at [Generic Connection Framework](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/genericframework/). Here you can find ample information, sample code snippets and get to know various connection methodologies available for JavaME.